# Adding directory/* to classpath

Tags: eclipse-juno

I want to run my application using the Eclipse equivalent of 'java -cp "mydir/*" '. That is, I want to make use of class path wild cards as described here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html.

Is there a way for me to do this in Eclipse (Juno)? Perhaps a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Follow mentioned steps in Eclipse:

1. Right Click on the project
2. Click on "Run As"
3. Click on "Run Configurations"
4. Access "Classpath" tab
5. Select "User Entries" and click on "Advance"
6. Select option "Add Folders"/"Add External Folder" and click "OK"
7. Select appropriate folder and click "Apply"
8. Last "Run"

Comment: This will work for directories containing resources like images, files, etc. But not for directories containing jars. I want to make use of the class path wild card feature in Java6+ so I can have the JVM expand the wildcard and add all the jars within that directory to the classpath.